# Installing ornaments

Tags: packages, mactex

I am trying to install the Ornaments package: http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/pgfornament/

I am using a Mac with MacTeX 2012.

I have followed the instructions in the package ReadMe file without success.

I see many answers saying that packages need to be installed at `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/` - however the Library folder I have at that location does NOT contain a folder called `texmf`.

Could someone please provide me with the COMPLETE path that each of the files contained in the package need to be placed at?

Comment: Add the folder in Library; there is no `texmf` folder until you create it. Don't worry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to install packages in addition to the MacTeX distribution, you need to set up the directory structure yourself in that location. [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) has written an App that does this for you automatically. That App is available [here](https://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/).

Alternatively, if you want to install the file structure yourself (or for anyone who does not have a Mac, as Alan's App only works for Mac computers), here is some [documentation](http://ctan.mackichan.com/tds/tds.html) that explains the file structure and a [summary](http://ctan.mackichan.com/tds/tds.html#Summary) of what the file structure should be.

Comment: Thanks @egreg and @Adam , those two hints did the trick. Alan Munn's script worked a charm.

For future reference (as it isn't clearly specified in the ornaments documentation), here are two clarifications:

1. Ornaments must be called with `\usepackage{pgfornament}` and not `\usepackage{ornament}`

2. Inside `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex` create a folder called `pgfornament` and place every file that comes with the pgfornament in there, EXCEPT for the folders `am` and `vectorian` which should be placed in `~/Library/texmf/tex/generic`