# Citations and Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, jabref

Before I begin: I'm sorry for the probably rudimentary question I'll be asking. Please be sure it's not for lack of trying/research.

I'm using `TeXShop`. I've got my document. I have a `.bib` file, saved in the same folder as all the stuff `TeXShop` generates when I run it (I'm using `JabRef`).

I cannot get in-text citations or a bibliography running.

I have at the bottom of my document

`\bibliographystyle{plain}`

and

`\bibliography {$Users/my name/Documents/Latex/name of bib file}`

I have also put `\cite{Ref_key6}` in the document.

All I'm getting is when I look at the document after hitting "typeset" is a `[?]` where the citation should be and a section called "References" with nothing written under it .

If there is a relatively jargon-free explanation as to how to get `TeXshop` to see my `.bib` file and how to get my citations in I'd be deeply appreciative.

Comment: Are you running `BibTeX`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Apologies, apologies-I ran Bibtex and received the error message 'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading adam's paper.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "ref_key6"

Given how slow I am in my learnings with technology, if any help is forthcoming I also ask for a bit of patience.
(There were 2 error messages)

Comment: @adam Is ref_key6 the actual name of your citation key? Also, are there any accented characters in your BibTeX file? Try changing your citation key to 'test' and eliminating accented characters. Then, try compiling a document that looks like:
`\documentclass{article}`
`\usepackage{natbib}`
`\begin{document}`
`\citep{test}`
`\bibliographystyle{plain}`
`\bibliography{my_bibliography}`
`\end{document}`
Doing this is how you compile a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe/3301#3301), which will allow us to better help you.

Comment: If you can create a minimal `.bib` file and a minimal `.tex` file that reproduce the same errors and update the question by copying and pasting that minimal code, then we will likely be able to help you faster. :-)

Comment: Also, I suppose I should have asked which package you're using, rather than assuming you're using `natbib`.

Comment: Do you get any warnings about the `$Users` part of your path specification?  That seems odd to me, but maybe it's OK on (what?) MacTeX.  If it is causing a problem, there should be a warning like `I couldn't open database file <specified path to your bib file>`.

Answer (score 4):

In order to successfully use `BibTeX`, you need to execute the following sequence of commands:

1. run `latex` on the `.tex` file
2. run `bibtex`
3. run `latex` again
4. run `latex` again

The first pass of `latex` detects a citation command in your `.tex` file, as well as the `\bibliographystyle{...}` and `\bibliography{...}` commands. Then, running `bibtex` formats the citation based on the `\bibliographystyle{...}` command. Running `latex` the second time makes the appropriate links, and, finally, running `latex` the third time puts everything in place.

(In TeXShop, you run `latex` by either clicking on `Typeset` in the window or by the shortcut `COMMAND+T`; `bibtex` is run by changing the dropdown menu next to the `Typeset` button to `BibTeX` and then clicking `Typeset` or by using the shortcut `SHIFT+COMMAND+B`.)

A couple things you may want to note:

First, if the `.bib` file is in the same directory as the `.tex` file, you do not need to specify the entire file path.

Second, you probably want to avoid having spaces in the name of your `.bib` file. If the name, for example, is `my bibliography.bib`, you probably want to change it to `my_bibliography.bib`, and you can include it simply with `\bibliography{my_bibliography}`, leaving off the file extension.

Third, if these instructions are confusing, there is an engine called `pdflatexmk`, which is, I think, a Perl script that was written to execute `latex` and `bibtex` the correct number of times on a `.tex` file. This is available as an engine with any recent version of TeXShop. By default, it is inactive. If you type:

```
mv ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/Latexmk/pdflatexmk.engine ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/
```

into the command line (i.e., Terminal) it will move this script into the active folder for you, and then you can access this from the dropdown menu in TeXShop right next to the `Typeset` button, after quitting and reopening TeXShop. (You can also do this by using 'drag & drop' techniques and Finder, though you will probably need to [reveal your Library folder](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/productivity/how-to-reveal-your-library-folder-in-lion-or-mountain-lion/), if you're running a recent OS X.)

Finally, a suggestion: you need not make separate `.bib` files for each document that you write in `LaTeX`. You can make one 'master' file, and put it in the `~\Library\texmf\bibtex\bib` directory (which is a place that will always be found when you run `latex`, `bibtex`, and/or `pdflatexmk`). **Only** citations that you have cited with a `\cite{...}` command will actually show up in the References section of the document. I find that this is a good way to manage citations, rather than having separate files for everything, particularly if there are works that you you end up citing multiple times.

---

### Update (as per some recent comments):

First, make sure that your [TeX distribution is up to date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution).

Then, if you have not already set up the requisite `texmf` directory structure for adding your own `.sty` files, `.bib` files, etc., you can follow the [instructions here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123288/installing-ornaments/123290#123290) to do so.

After following those instructions, you can move your `.bib` file to the `~\Library\texmf\bibtex\bib` directory. This should take care of any problems that `latex` \ `bibtex` might have in locating the `.bib` file. (Again, doing this might require you to [reveal your Library folder](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/productivity/how-to-reveal-your-library-folder-in-lion-or-mountain-lion/).)

Moreover, MWEs for both the `.bib` file and `.tex` file will look as follows:

`.bib` file, which is named `master.bib` and located in `~\Library\texmf\bibtex\bib`:

```
@article{ref_key6,
Author = {Example Author},
Journal = {Example Journal},
Number = {1},
Pages = {1-32},
Title = {Example Title},
Volume = {1},
Year = {2013}}
```

and the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

I am going to cite `ref\_key6' here.\citep{ref_key6}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{master}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a prompt and thorough reply!

I've performed (1) - (4) above and the result is the same: a [?} where the citation should be in text and nothing under "references" (and I performed (1)-(4) without making changes to what my tex situation was before, with the \bibliography{plain} and \bibliography {mybibfile} and the in text command \cite{ref_key6}

I'm being told I need to click something about "roots" or type into the tex document something about natib.

Again, thank you so much for the help and I think we can figure this out!

Comment: Do you have a recent version of TeX Live installed? And did you put `\usepackage{natbib}` in the preamble of your `.tex` document?

Comment: I have the Tex Live utility and I did not put that command into the preamble. I put the command into my preamble (apologies for not specifying that both \bibliography commands are at the end of my content) and performed (1)-(4) and nothing has changed.

Comment: @adam Are you still using the `\cite{...}` command? Try changing to either `\citet{...}` or `\citep{...}`. You can see [this reference sheet](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) for `natbib` commands.

Comment: Neither of them worked-is the command inside the fancy bracket correct, {ref_key6}? Could that be it?

Comment: @adam So as long as that is the name of the citation in your `.bib` file, that should be fine. Take a look at the MWE's that I just posted as an update to this question. Make sure that your `.bib` file and `.tex` files look like those. Those MWEs compile perfectly on my machine.

Comment: Thank you-I'm in the process of doing as you suggest. May you please spell out the acronym MWE for me? I'm a neophyte at all of this (I'm sure you've noticed in an obvious way).

Comment: @adam In the series of comments on your original question, above, I provided a link explaining what a MWE is. In brief, it's the smallest piece of code that produces the same error or the smallest piece of code that compiles. The link above will have more of an explanation. [Here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) it is again, just in case.

Comment: Apologies and more thanks-I'm a bit fried; long night with all of this. So as per request, I have that file structure, I have the .bib where it should be, I have what I working on in TexShop in that structure under tex>latex>mydocument and still nothing. But I'm off to retire for now, work in the morning, but I'll be back cracking on this tomorrow. Thanks again for all those taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

I just met the same problem as yours: "?" for the citation and nothing under the "References". I just made two changes and now the problem has been solved.

1. As Adam points out, you probably want to avoid having spaces in the name of your `.bib` file and change the space to "_".
2. You might want to add to following command in your TeX field
   `\nocite{*}` before the bibliography.

Then I found with excitement that the problem was solved.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: What `\nocite{*}` does is to add *all* references in the `.bib` file to the reference list, which may not be desirable. By default only the works that are actually cited end up in the reference list. `\nocite{<citation key>}` adds an item to the list without generating a citation in the text, and `\nocite{*}` adds everything.