# BibDesk doesn't import article information and cite key is useless with Bibtex, even after manual import

Tags: bibtex, bibdesk

I think there is a communication problem between my thesis latex file (and the bibliography instructions) and the Bibdesk: what i use to contain my bibliography. When i first installed BibDesk, I dragged my papers and some of them were automatically annotated. Some did not. So I manually annotated them. while the automatic annotation citekeys were Author:yearaa (King:2002aa), the manual ones were :cm, :bc, etc..

I used `\cite{}` and `\citep{}` commands with the manually processed citekeys and it didn't work. I changed them to the same format: Author:yearaa and it didnt work either. I dragged the citation from bibdesk to latex file. didint work either. What do you recommend for me?

I don't know if it is enough to information so here, in Bibliography tex file, i have:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\label{app:bibliography} 

\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

and general thesis configurations:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage{minitoc,arsclassica,gensymb,numprint,xtab,setspace,amssymb,caption,pdfpages,csvsimple}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

(I didnt know which ones are useful. I'm still new to latex.) Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is in `classicthesis-config`? Have you loaded the `natbib` package (`\usepackage{natbib}`)? `\citep{}` is a command from that package. Additionally, what is "not working"? Are you getting error messages or question marks or what? Also, are you running `latex` and `bibtex` the proper number of times?

Comment: What would be the most helpful is if you could create a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: sorry for being so unspecific. I don't know what to include for a MWE, my thesis is composed of several chapters and all have different tex files with a main tex file that calls all of them together. yes i loaded >natbib package. I am getting question marks.After typesetting once, i run a macro for bibliography from Macros>Applescript>Bibliography and it processes three times. still the automatically imported ones can be cited, other are not.

Comment: Are you running `latex`, `bibtex`, then `latex`, then `latex` again? This answer explains the procedure a bit: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124159/citations-and-bibliography/124161#124161

Comment: Could be a matter of [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) but with the given information, i cannot tell. If you can, please mark as dupe. Right now, i VtC as unclear.